# Magento Collections (Get Products by Type ID in specific order

Tags: php, mysql, magento, entity-attribute-value

I want to get a collection of products from magento in a specific order.

1. Simple Products
2. Configurable Products
3. Grouped Products

How would I add a filter that will retrieve the products in that order

Comment: maybe a groupBy ? -_- what have you tried ?

Comment: I havn't tried group by, maybe that should work.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible directly. I have 2 solutions:

**1.** Get your products in 3 different collections using `addAttributeToFilter` where `attribute name` is `type_id`. For the condition you can use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE`, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE` and  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED`.

Example:

```
$simple_products = $model->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
```

---

**2.** Add custom attribute from the admin panel (e.g. `1` for simple, `2` for configurable, `3` for grouped products etc.) and use it with `addAttributeToSort`.

Comment: how did you get $model

Comment: $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');